# Replace string either lowercase or uppercase

Tags: scripting, ansible, yaml

I am writing a playbook to replace a string in three files. That string can be written either in lowercase or uppercase. Here is my code :

```
---
  - name: "Modif string"
    hosts: myhosts
    tasks:
    - name: "Replace line"
      replace:
        path: ~/Documents/{{ item  }}
        regexp: 'test'
        replace: 'new'
      with_items:
      - 'file'
      - 'file1'
      - 'file2'
```

How can I make it work so the string 'test' is amended either it is written in lowercase or uppercase? Also what if there is randomly letter uppercase or lowercase in that string?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote that script. Works like a charm.

```
- name: "Other test"
  hosts: raspi
  vars:
    text_to_replace:
      - {regexp: '(?i)(test)', line: 'new'}
      - {regexp: '10', line: '20'}
    my_files:
      - {file: 'file'}
      - {file: 'file1'}
      - {file: 'file2'}
  tasks:
    - name: "Replace"
      replace:
        path: ~/test/{{item.1.file}}
        regexp: "{{item.0.regexp}}"
        replace: "{{item.0.line}}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{text_to_replace}}"
        - "{{my_files}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
  - name: "Replace line"
    replace:
      path: ~/Documents/{{ item  }}
      regexp: '(?i)test'
      replace: 'new'
```

Comment: What if I want to amend another string in these files? For instance I want to replace an IP address plus the string 'test.

Comment: will it occur only once? if so, you can use lineinfile module

Comment: I would like to test these two strings in multiple files and amend them in the event they are present.

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: I hope this answer gave you some insights